# reading latest from sftp server

Tags: file, download, sftp

I have a requirement to download the latest file from sftp server.I have written the below code in shell script but am not able to download the file.
After retrieving the file am getting the below Error

Invalid command

Please help me how to download  the file.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='xx.xx.xx.nxx'
USER='xx'
PASSWD='xx'
sftp $USER@$HOST <<EOF
cd  /inbound
file=$(ls -ltr *.xml | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}')
get $file
EOF
```

Comment: I modified the above code as below
mget $(ls -ltr *.xml | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}')
But the script is failing in bash script.
Please help how to fix in bash script

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run shell commands in sftp, but sftp is not a shell. The command `ls` happens to exist in sftp, but not `$()`, `tail`, or `awk`. To see this, just type `sftp $USER@$HOST` to open a sftp session and type `help` to get all of the available commands.

So what you need to do is to execute the shell commands using ssh to get the filename. So something like this:

```
file=$(ssh $USER@$HOST "ls -ltr /inbound/*.xml" | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}')
```

This execute the command `ls -ltr /inbound/*.xml` remotely on the server. The output of that is then processed by your shell script locally. Or maybe more efficiently by doing the processing on the server:

```
file=$(ssh $USER@$HOST "ls -ltr /inbound/*.xml | tail -1 | awk '{print \$NF}'")
```

Now the shell variable `file` contains the name of the newest file. Then you can download that file with sftp as

```
sftp $USER@$HOST:$file .
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ,this gave me more insight into the sftp concept.
i followed the steps by connecting to sftp server and changed to inbound directory , then i issued the command to get the latest file
ls -1t *.xml
but it is displaying all the files, i need only the latest file from the server.
Below are the available option for ls command in the sftp.
ls [-1aflnrSt] [path]              Display remote directory listing
The version am using is SFTP protocol version 3.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Are you sure you didn't just do the ssh $USER@$HOST "ls -ltr /inbound/*.xml" part? Because that indeed will give you the whole list of file, hence the | tail -1 and such. In any case, I've edited the answer to include a maybe more efficient version.

Comment: This is still not working , i am pasting the complete source code  with the error message here. 
!/bin/bash
HOST='x.x.x.x'
USER='xx'
PASSWD='xx'
file=$(ssh $USER@$HOST "ls -ltr /inbound/*.xml | tail -1 | awk '{print \$NF}'")
sftp $USER@$HOST:$file .

Error message
usage: sftp [-1Cv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-F ssh_config]
            [-o ssh_option] [-P sftp_server_path] [-R num_requests]
            [-S program] [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
       sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
       sftp [user@]host[:dir[/]]
       sftp -b batchfile [user@]host

Comment: i gave a full stop after $file.is it required?

Comment: Oh, here is a thought. When you just type ssh $USER@$HOST, does it ask for a password? I use private keys instead of passwords, so I don't get asked for a password. The script in my answer assumes that. If you do use passwords, you may want to consider using private keys instead. Or alternatively, install something like sshpass. See here: https://sshpass.sourceforge.io/

Comment: it does ask for password

Comment: and proceed to the next step.unfortunately i donot have permission to install sshpass as it is governed by linux administrators.
is there any alternative way by which i can get the file.
sorry for the inconvinience as outcome of this script depends on another teams work.

Comment: Yes, you can use a private key. Instructions are here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2 . Just leave the passphrase empty as you generate the private key and you should not be asked for a password when using ssh to log into the server. Alternatively, you can compile sshpass and just use the binary without installing it anywhere.